# Como eliminar una parte de la url href con expresion regulares php

Tags: php, regex

Quiero eliminar una parte de una url en href por expresiones regulares o que me recomiendan? Tomar en cuenta que las url son cambiantes.

Entrada

```
<a href="http://example.com/tyunn" class="example"> example</a> <a href="https://urlcambiante.com/other/other" class="example">url example</a>
```

Salida esperada

```
 <a href="tyunn" class="example"> example</a><a href="other/other" class="example">url example</a>
```

Tomar en cuenta que las urls van cambiando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hice un patrón que creo que te funcionará bien:

```
<?php 

$url1 = 'http://example.com/tyunn';

$url2 = 'https://urlcambiante.com/other/other';

$expRegular = '/([a-z]+:\/\/+[a-z-.]+?\/)/i';

echo preg_replace($expRegular, '', $url1);

echo preg_replace($expRegular, '', $url2);

?>
```

Explicación:

- "[a-z]+://" -> El patrón contiene letras de la "a" a la "z", dos puntos ":" y dos slash "//".
- "[a-z-.]" -> El patrón contiene letras de la "a" a la "z" y puntos ".".
- "?/" -> Para que busque el caracter "/" una vez.
- "i" -> Para que no sea sensible a las mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Espero haberlo explicado bien.